# installing software on MacBook in /usr/bin

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, install

I'm trying to install a set of software tools, the "PureScript compiler", on my Mac. I actually installed an older version with npm, like

```
sudo npm install -g purs
```

I need to get the latest version, and it seems to be available only as a direct download from here: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases and not yet available through npm.

Right now, the old version of `purs` is in `/usr/local/bin`. Should I just download this new version and copy it there? Or is there a better way to install this?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122612/intro-to-osx-system-directory-conventions?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot install to `/usr/bin` because that [directory is protected by SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)

However, `/usr/local/` is not covered and you can write to that directory.   Using `/usr/local/bin` is perfectly fine for what you're attempting to do as it's both writeable and in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Amen to using `/usr/local` and a nod to using http://brew.sh to get node and other tools set up in the local space in the first place. Then you can use `npm` and such to add on that location.